# Declaring beans inside a ConfigurationProperties class, using the same configuration property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired

I have a java class called `UserData`, and it has a field called `users` that I'm reading from `application.yml` in my spring-boot application, by using the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

In this class I want to declare another bean to find the oldest user. When I try to create the `getOldestUser` bean, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in the initialization of `getOldestUser` bean, because the `users` variable is `null`.

Here's how my code looks like:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class UserData {
    Map<String, Integer > users;

    @Bean
    public String getOldestUser() {
        Integer maxAge = 0;
        String oldestUser = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : users.entrySet()) { // This line throws NPE, because 'users' is null
            if(entry.getValue() > maxAge) {
                oldestUser = entry.getKey();
                maxAge = entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return oldestUser;
    }
}
```

Here's the users declaration in application.yml:

```
users:
  joey: 32
  jim: 29
```

How can I access the fields of the class bean `userData` inside it's method bean `getOldestUser`? I've also tried passing the `userData` bean as an argument to this method, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to split the configuration part from properties to separate classes.

Also, the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation needs to have a prefix which binds all child properties to the fields.

Lastly, the method `getOldestUser` which you made as a spring bean is just a calculating function which can be under the `UserProperties` class and called whenever you need this data, spring is not required :).

```yaml
data:
  users:
    joey: 32
    jim: 29
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "data")
public class UserProperties{
    private Map<String, Integer > users;

    public String getOldestUser() {
        Integer maxAge = 0;
        String oldestUser = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : users.entrySet()) { // This line throws NPE, because 'users' is null
            if(entry.getValue() > maxAge) {
                oldestUser = entry.getKey();
                maxAge = entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return oldestUser;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(UserProperties.class)
public class UserConfiguration {}
```